# Excel - How to add value after 3rd /

Tags: excel, replace

I have excel file with one value that need to be edited. It's link to a image.
My link template looks like this:

this

```
http://website.com/something/brand/product/product_name/image.jpg
```

I need to add 'medium' after /product/

so my template would be

this

```
http://website.com/something/brand/product/medium/product_name/image.jpg
```

example:

```
http://website.com/cake/cutie/bigcakes/pink_caramel/hr74.jpg
```

would be

```
http://website.com/cake/cutie/bigcakes/medium/pink_caramel/hr74.jpg
```

Of course all products are different, so can i maybe say something like, add `medium/` after 6th `/` ? I don't know how else, as its huge file with thousands of products, brands and product names.

Comment: `=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),6))` will find the sixth instance of `/` for example.

Comment: Thanks for edit Radim :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the formula of @SkipIntro, you can use the `CONCATENATE`, `LEFT` and `MID` formulae to get your desired result.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),6))),"medium",MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),6)),100))
```

This assumes your link template is in cell A1. If it's in any other cell, replace the `A1` with the required cell address.

EDIT:

I overlooked a much simpler one ^^; :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),6),CHAR(1),"/medium/")
```

Comment: Thanks Skip Intro, Jerry and Barry that's just did it! Love that simple 2nd one, Jerry. My spreadsheet is now ready. I'll save this for future too, very cool that I learned this. Thank a lot - have an AWESOME day all!

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate Skip Intro's suggestion into a REPLACE function like this

`=REPLACE(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),6))+1,0,"medium/")`